# Xcode show .xib and .storyboard only as XML

Tags: xcode, storyboard, xcode13

I don't know the reason, but Xcode from today won't open `.xib` and `.storyboard` files as visual editor, but only as XML.

If I right click on one of these file, trying to choose `"Open as..."` this is the result. Very strange.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Load the corresponding view controller source in the assistant editor, the main editor switched to the IB view. From then on, all storyboards and Xib loaded as IB views.

`Select storyboard > Editor > Assistant`

All storyboards loaded as IB views.

Not sure it's feature or bug in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when the **Code Review** view is enabled. Once you disable it in the upper right corner of the Editor, the project file (or the storyboard) is displayed again in the familiar way.

[image: location and explanation how to disable Code Review]

(copied the answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76718743/585697 )