# xcode 14.3 on m1 show old project file as xml

Tags: xcode

Trying to open an old iOS project in my new M1 14.3 xcode.  the project file is showing as XML :-(
[image]

Also, storyboard files are show as XML files as well :-(

The project does still build and runs just fine.  Any trick, tips or suggestions?

Comment: What XML are you referring to? Do you mean the `<None>`? That's not XML, that's just a menu label stating there are no options available in the "Open As" menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens when the **Code Review** view is enabled. Once you disable it in the upper right corner of the Editor, the project file (or the storyboard) is displayed again in the familiar way.

[image: location and explanation how to disable Code Review]